# KDB: How to convert relative path to absolute path?

Tags: format, relative-path, kdb, absolute-path

Is there a way to convert a relative path to an absolute path in KDB?

For example:

```
filePath: `$concat[localPath,"\\",inProcessID,"\\",filename]
```

Which returns:

```
`..\..\code\products\Q\ShortLocator2\Request Files\1\Locate_CCL_11-13-2018_074736.csv
```

And then now I want to convert this to absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately you should solve the problem of why your "localPath" variable is relative in the first place, but here is an ugly function to solve your problem:

```
q){hsym `$("\\" sv neg[c]_"\\" vs system"cd"),"\\","\\" sv (c:count where ".."~/:a)_a:"\\" vs string x}[filePath]
`:C:\Users\code\products\Q\ShortLocator2\Request Files\1\Locate_CCL_11-13-201..
```

It is specific to windows

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the canonical path to the file?  If you are on linux readlink is commonly available and may help:

```
system "readlink -f ", filepath
```

But this obviously doesn't help for Windows (which it looks like you are using?).  I'm not aware of a similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current working directory by typing...

`` q)homepath:`$system"pwd"     // for Linux
,`/home/user
q)homepath:`$system"cd"      // for Windows
,`C:\\Users\\user ``

To get the absolute path do...

`` q).Q.dd[hsym homepath; filepath]
`:/home/user/.. ``

This should return the absolute path.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: "cd" is trapped by kdb and should work identically across windows and Linux?

Comment: `.Q.dd` will not resolve the dots, it just concatenates